# The safest way to avoid SQL injection for conditional query with JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using JDBCTemplate to make a query to connect to PSQL. There's **req** parameter that contains 3 strings will be sent from a client,

1. "all"
2. "0"
3. "1"

From the code **A** I have no idea how to deal with "all" to get both **true** and **false** records.

A - A stuck solution,

```
    public List<Product> getProductsByStatus(String req){
        Boolean active = false;

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE active = ?";

        switch (req) {
            case "0":
                active = false;
                break;
            case "1":
                active = true;
                break;  
            case "all":
                active = ""; // I don't know what to do.
                break;        
            default:
                break;
        }
    
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Product>(Product.class), active);
        
        return products;
    }
```

Then I'm using the **B** which is the current and working solution but it is not safe for SQL injections.

B - A current solution,

```
    public List<Product> getProductsByStatus(String req){

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products";

        switch (req) {
            case "0":
                sql += " WHERE active = false;";
                break;
            case "1":
                sql += " WHERE active = true;";
                break;        
            default:
                break;
        }

        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Product>(Product.class));
        
        return products;
    }
```

Is there any proper of safer way to do this without a risk of SQL injection ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second solution is correct and it's the common solution around. However, this is typically done using ORMs that implement all this dynamic SQL behind the scenes for you. If you are using plain JDBCTemplate this is the way to go.

Comment: Note that your B solution, is currently also safe from SQL injection, since no external input is injected in the content of the SQL you are generating..

Comment: There is no injection possible in solution b. One statement is just *get all* and the other two don't get a parameter injected, instead you route every possible parameter by appending. Both safe, but in general, the way (without ORMs) would be the use of a `PreparedStatement`, I think.

Comment: The B solution won't be cached properly, tho; variables and queries are converted into procedures internally, to speed-up future queries. Don't abuse of query composition. You could use a IN condition instead.